# Typescript constructor: accept string for enum

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using TypeScript to define a constructor for a model in Angular. One of the properties in the model is set as an enum with a few possible string values. This works fine if I pass an enum value to the constructor.
The problem is that I need call the constructor based on an API response which returns a string for the value that needs to be mapped to that property.

Is there any way of passing a string (as long as it is one of the values defined in the enum) to the constructor?

Enum:

```
export enum TestTypes {
    FIRST = 'first',
    SECOND = 'second',
}

export class Test {
    this.myType: TestTypes;

    constructor(options: {type: TestTypes}) {
        this.myType = options.type;
    }
}
```

The following works
`const a = new Test({type:TestTypes.FIRST});`

What I would like to achieve:
`const b = new Test({type:'first'})`

Should I do the following? 
`const b = new Test({type:TestTypes['first']})`

Comment: `const b = new Test({type:TestTypes['first']})`?

Comment: const b=new Test({type:TestTypes.FIRST});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to go is to change your `enum` to a straight dictionary like this:

```
const literal = <L extends string | number | boolean>(l: L) => l;

export const TestTypes = {
  FIRST: literal('first'),
  SECOND: literal('second'),
};

export type TestTypes = (typeof TestTypes)[keyof typeof TestTypes]
```

The `literal()` function is a helper that prompts the compiler to interpret the value [as a string literal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) instead of widening to `string`.

Now, the value `TestTypes.FIRST` is exactly the string `"first"`, the value `TestTypes.SECOND` is exactly the string `"second"`, and the type `TestTypes` is exactly the union `"first"|"second"`.  That lets your class work as desired:

```
export class Test {
  myType: TestTypes; // this is an annotation, not an initializer, right?

  constructor(options: { type: TestTypes }) {
    // options.type, not type  
    this.myType = options.type;
  }
}

const a = new Test({ type: TestTypes.FIRST }); // okay
const b = new Test({ type: "first" }); // okay... it's the same thing
```

---

If you want to keep `TestTypes` as an `enum`, you can get what you want, but it's too much hoop jumping in my opinion.

First, if you wanted a standalone function that accepted either the `enum` or the right `string` values, you could make a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) like this:

```
declare function acceptTestTypesOrString<E extends string>(
  k: E & (Extract<TestTypes, E> extends never ? never : E)
): void;
```

I don't know if I should explain that, but it takes advantage of the fact that, say, `TestTypes.FIRST extends "first"`.  Let's see if it works:

```
acceptTestTypesOrString(TestTypes.FIRST) // okay
acceptTestTypesOrString(TestTypes.SECOND) // okay
acceptTestTypesOrString("first") // okay
acceptTestTypesOrString("second") // okay
acceptTestTypesOrString("third") // error
```

Looks good.  But you want this as a constructor function.  And you [can't make a constructor function generic](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10860#issuecomment-246456721).  Instead you could make the whole class generic, like this:

```
export class Test<E extends string> {
  myType: E; // this is an annotation, not an initializer, right?

  constructor(options: { 
    type: E & (Extract<TestTypes, E> extends never ? never : E) 
  }) {
    // options.type, not type  
    this.myType = options.type;
  }
}

const a = new Test({ type: TestTypes.FIRST }); // okay
const b = new Test({ type: "first" }); // also okay
```

In this case, `a` will be of type `Test<TestTypes.FIRST>` and `b` will be of type `Test<"first">`.  They are mostly interchangeable, but it seems suboptimal to drag around a generic type for the whole class when you only want it for the constructor.

But it works.

---

Okay, hope one of those ideas help.  Good luck!

Comment: Is it possible to go the second way (with enum) in TS 2.9, without the `unknown` type? Is it ever necessary?

Comment: Oh I forgot that `unknown` won't appear until TS3.0.  Changed it.